# Unable to get JAXB context

Tags: jaxb

I have java classes generated by XSD.
But when am trying to get JAXB context (while unmarshlling) it hits a dead end.
No errors,no print statements will be executed after this line. Nothing happens.

I have tried following methods

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(package)
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(class)
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(package,contextloader)
```

but every option is failing.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

`JAXBContext.newInstance` will return you an instance of `JAXBContext`.  From that you need to create instances of `Unmarshaller` to convert XML to objects, and instances of `Marshaller` to convert those objects back to XML.